# Measurement inaccuracy using Digital Caliper

Tags: measurements, instrumentation

I am using a digital caliper (0.01-200mm) to measure the dimensions (in mm) of plastic blocks. In this case 3D printed blocks but the problem also applies to off the shelf products. The problem is that almost all the time (let's say 90% of the time), it was impossible to get a consistent results. For example, even measuring the width, depending on how hard/soft I pressed the gripper, I got different answers (first and second digits after the decimal kept changing). If I flipped the block upside down and measured the same width, I also got different readings. Even the same width, depending on where in the gripper of the caliper touched the sides of the block, I also got different results. Is it due to measurement errors, sensitivity of the caliper (perhaps in this case mine is too sensitive to change?), accuracy of the caliper, inconsistence of 3D printed parts or a combination of these factors? What can I do to get more accurate measurements (down to 2 digits after the decimal if possible)?

Comment: Lightly press the calipers closed. zero the calipers. then use the same force to measure the block. I think you'll find better consistency.

Comment: Do a web / YouTube search for "gauge repeatability and reproducibility". It's a concern in manufacturing quality systems.

Comment: I have a digital caliper, my son looked at it and said I would get more accuracy with a steel ruler. What is the make of it? Does it read to 3 decimal places? Does it come with a calibration certificate? has it ever been sent for calibration?

Comment: @SolarMike That must be a terrible caliper lol

Comment: @DKNguyen yes came from Al*i, cost 12 bucks... probably better used as an adjustable spanner... :)

Answer (score 2):

> measuring the width, depending on how hard/soft I pressed the gripper

It is normal behaviour for measurement devices to give different readings under different measurement pressures. One needs to develop the skill to produce consistent pressure to get repeatability.

> What can I do to get more accurate measurements (down to 2 digits after the decimal if possible)?

This is an unreasonable expectation to ask for from plastic, from a (presumably) desktop 3D printer, and from calipers.

Metal holds holds tolerances better and deforms less than plastic and is machined on mills and lathes of superior quality to your 3D printer. A measurement precision of 0.001"/0.0254mm is the maximum precision used for casual metal working. In a stretch, might go to 0.0005"/0.0125mm but no farther except in special circumstances. Measuring with higher resolution than that gets troublesome because workpiece and tool deformation, as well as and expansion due to temperature become factors. You are asking way too much when you ask for double decimal digit mm precision. The tolerances listed are also not within the realm of calipers.

Calipers are generally not trusted for resolutions below 0.005"/0.1mm, despite how fine the graduations/resolution on the instrument.

This is because to design of calipers is not well suited when measurement pressure is important such as in higher resolution measurements where workpiece and tool deformation becomes significant sources of error.

If you really did want to measure with such precision though, then you need a micrometer. Micrometers are designed to give much better tactile feel to get consistent measurement pressures to enable fine measurements. This is also conducive to measuring pliable materials with lots of give. Even a typical micrometer will only have a resolution of 0.001"/0.0254mm. A higher end micrometer will have a graduations for a resolution twice as good which is 0.0005"/0.0125mm". Skill and practice are required to develop the feel to get consistent measurement pressure for repeatable and accurate readings, just like calipers. However, since the expected precision is higher, skill and practice is more important in the use of a micrometer.

> Is it due to measurement errors, sensitivity of the caliper (perhaps in this case mine is too sensitive to change?), accuracy of the caliper, inconsistence of 3D printed parts or a combination of these factors?

However, if your workpieces are not parallel, straight, and smooth, then neither micrometer nor caliper is suited. You need point measurements in this case which means you now need a granite surface plate, and a plunger or lever indicator mounted on a base. You place the workpiece on the surface plate and run the indicator along the workpiece to measure variations in it. If you need absolute measurements then you will need to set your indicator using a reference first such as gage blocks, since indicators only measure variance. They also tend to come in two resolutions: 0.0005" and 0.0002", or 0.01mm and 0.0002mm for the metric. The higher resolution kind give up travel.

Plungers indicators are cheaper, have longer travel, more rugged, and can have much larger probes to ignore surface irregularities. They are also better suited for measuring actual height since if you get the plunger square with the workpiece there is no cosine error.

But lever probes can get into tiny or ackward places and are better suited for dragging across the workpiece since they have a lever which allows even tiny probes to ride over large imperfections (not that you can't also scan the workpiece with a plunger), but the lever introduces cosine error so not as suitable for absolute measurement (not that you can't use it for that, just less convenient).

If you do not trust your 3D printer (and you probably shouldn't before you check it), this last method is what you need and it is what machinist use. You can also mount the indicator on your 3D printer head and run it along the table or other references to to determine machine straightness and perpendicularity.

Comment: Thank you very much for the details. I am comparing different 3D print filaments under different conditions (temperatures and extrusion multipliers). By changing these two variables, the dimensions of the printed blocks also change. Without accurate measurements, it is hard to tell which filament under what conditions can produce prints that match as close to the original dimensions as my design. 

Another difficulty is that given the block is 10 mm thick, depending on where I put the Caliper, most of the time I got different values (even the one digit after the decimal).

Comment: @lovedrinking Sounds like the job for a surface plate and indicator. But it can cost. They are very fundamental and useful tools though. You might find you're using them every day. I do.

Comment: Thanks @DKNguyen
 I will try indicator and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Take 10 more measurements than you need and average the results.  Assuming the error is completely random and within a narrow range, the result should be very close to the true measurement.  If there is a bias to the error, you will need to find another method or account for the bias.